# reloading a div with javascript without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i want to reload a div when i click on a button, am looking for simplest code using JavaScript, i tried several codes but none of them worked,this is my last script and it didn't work either

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8dyw.jpg)

Comment: Just curious, is it somehow easier for you to take and upload a screenshot than copy-paste the code like required?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method in jquery to get the content as well as modify the content of a div.

Find the working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dke1Lw5n/

Find the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btn_click').on('click', function () {
                $('#publish').html($('#publish').html() + 1);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="publish">5</div>
        <button type="button" id="btn_click">clickme</button>
    </body>
</html>
```